# Getting Mongo results from only previous month avg by default

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this data in mongodb:

```
 [
{

    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-08-08T04:53:51.840Z"),
    "cummulativeKWH" : 368.5,
     "frequency" : "50.12"
},
{

    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-08-08T04:53:51.840Z"),
    "cummulativeKWH" : 369.5,
     "frequency" : "50.12"
},
{

    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2018-09-03T04:53:51.840Z"),
    "cummulativeKWH" : 369.5,
     "frequency" : "50.12"
},
]
```

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline. I need to take the average of cummulativeKWH for that previous month only I am using filter methods and selected dates. How to get last previous month avg of cummulativeKWH (ex:aug 1-to-aug 31) only by default without selection and without filters.
Anyone please suggest me.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    'createDate': {'$gte':ISODate("2018-08-01"), '$lte':ISODate("2018-08-31") } 
  }},
  {$group: {_id:null,
   cummulative: {$avg:"$cummulativeKWH"}
}}
])
```

I am trying this aggregation I got the output but how to get without date selection and without filters how to get default previous  month avg of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since 3.6 version**

You have to extract year and month from your date.
try below aggregation

```
db['02'].aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {$and:[
                  {$eq:[{$year:"$CreateDate"},{$year:new Date()}]},
                  {$eq:[1,{$subtract:[{$month:new Date()},{$month:"$CreateDate"}]}]},  
                ]}
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
            _id:{year:{$year:"$CreateDate"},month:{$month:"$CreateDate"}},
                    avg : {$avg:"$cummulativeKWH"}

            }
        },
    ],
);
```

**Before version 3.6**
you can use $redact stage :

db['02'].aggregate(

```
// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $group: {
        _id:{year:{$year:"$CreateDate"},month:{$month:"$CreateDate"}},
                avg : {$avg:"$cummulativeKWH"},       
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $redact: {
          $cond: {  if: { $and:[
            {$eq: [ "$_id.year", {$year:new Date()} ]}, 
            {$eq: [-1, {$subtract:[ "$_id.month", {$month:new Date()} ]}]}
            ]},
                  then: "$$KEEP",
                  else: "$$PRUNE"
          }
        }
    },
],
```

);

Result :

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2018), 
        "month" : NumberInt(8)
    }, 
    "avg" : 369.0
}
```

Comment: Hi matthPen month avg is there but how to get only previous month alternatively for example present sep month how to get aug month avg only ofter going oct month automatic get sep month avg value if any possible plese suggest me

Comment: for example how to show max( month -1) avg value please any one suggest me @ matthPen

Comment: Edited my answer : - added $match stage to get only relevant document,  -removed $addField stage and add year and month computation in group stage. Note that at this point ($group stage), only relevant documents are passed to the pipeline, so grouping by _id:null will get the same result. I keep it unchanged just to keep year and month information in result.

Comment: i will try this code but throw "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr", error please solve my problem @ matthPen

Comment: which version are you using? $expr came in 3.6

Comment: 3.4.4. @ matthPen

Comment: Does this solution account for the scenario where the month is January and subtracting 1 should roll the year back to the previous year?